# Remove axis on IDD chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm trying to visualize a time series using [IDD](https://github.com/predictionmachines/InteractiveDataDisplay). How can I remove the X axis that indicates float values from the chart and leave only time stamps?

Here is my code:

```
var timeSeriesChart = InteractiveDataDisplay.asPlot("chart");

var timeSeriesData = JSON.parse('{\
    "times":["2016-03-28 16:00","2016-03-28 17:00","2016-03-28 18:00"],\
    "time_locations":[0.6,1.2,1.8],\
    "values":[3.0, 4.0, 5.0]}');

timeSeriesChart.polyline("Time series", 
{
    y: timeSeriesData.values,
    x: false,
    stroke: "rgb(89,150,255)",
    thickness: 3
});

timeSeriesChart.addAxis("bottom", "labels", {
    labels: timeSeriesData.times,
    ticks: timeSeriesData.time_locations
});
```

[see the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi1nU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

`var numAxis = timeSeriesChart.getAxes("bottom");
numAxis[0].remove();`

To remove existing axis before adding your labeled axis.

And after you add your labeled axis, attach grid lines to this new axis:

`var gridLines = $('#chart > div[data-idd-plot="grid"]');
var grid = timeSeriesChart.get(gridLines[0]);
grid.xAxis = timeAxis.axis;`